# Avoid creating multiple files with wget

Tags: shell-script, wget

I use `wget` to call a link every 10 seconds like this:

```
#/bin/sh
while true; do
    wget http://www.some.random.link/to/some/PHP/script
    sleep 10
done
```

This produces empty files called `script_name.#` where `#` is incremented on every run.

Why does this happen?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's because wget downloads the output of your script (which, presumably, is empty) and saves it to a file, appending a number each time so as not to overwrite the previously downloaded file.

There's a couple of options for how to prevent this.

1. Prevent wget from downloading anything at all, using the `--spider` option:
   `wget --spider http://www.some.random.link/to/some/PHP/script`
   However, this may cause your script not to work since, IIRC, it only issues a `HEAD` request.
2. Download the output, but discard it by sending it to `/dev/null`:
   `wget -O /dev/null http://www.some.random.link/to/some/PHP/script`
3. Download the output, but delete if afterwards, using the `--delete-after` option:
   `wget --delete-after http://www.some.random.link/to/some/PHP/script`
4. For the sake of completeness, if you can live with one file, use the `-nc` option to prevent wget from downloading files that already exist locally:
   `wget -nc http://www.some.random.link/to/some/PHP/script`

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative fix, you could avoid using `wget` — which, as its name implies, is intended for *getting* web content from a given URL. In other words, it's built to be a "download" tool. (It is, of course, very flexible, as Indrek demonstrated in his answer. But its defaults work against your purposes.)

Since you don't need or *want* to actually download anything (you're just accessing the URL to fire off a server-side script), the `curl` command is a bit more appropriate for your script. It will write the results of its requests to stdout by default, instead of to a file.

So, replacing `wget` with `curl`  in your code above should fix the file-creation problem without any further work.

Comment: Specifically `curl --silent <address> 1>/dev/null` will do the job.

Comment: Generally, yes, that'd allow curl to operate silently regardless of the content being retrieved. However, not even really necessary in this case, since the remote server doesn't output anything (wget was "downloading" empty files), and curl is wonderfully free of output unless something goes wrong or there's data retrieved. That's what made curl so ideally suited to this particular application.